# HTTP POST Request to an Application Running on the Same Computer?

Tags: java, html, post, request

I'd really appreciate anyone with knowledge about how to communicate between applications to help me with my confusion.  I've been spending a lot of time trying to figure this out.
I am currently working on an electronic gradebook that among other things allows the user to store students and grades in a Java desktop application. I want to be able to send that information (assignment names, student grades, etc.) over the Internet through a stream to a Ruby on Rails SQLite3 database. The purpose is so that students can access reports relating to their grades from the Ruby on Rails application. I’m hoping to make the connection as simple as possible. Both the Java and Rails applications are mostly complete (although Rails SQLite3 database needs to be normalized).

I'm thinking about using an HTTP POST request, such as the one I'm working on below, to send the information from Java to the Rails database.  My question is as follows:

Since the web application CURRENTLY is not attached to a server but instead being run on a virtual machine is it possible to make an http request that, for demonstration/testing purposes, can connect from a Java to a Rails application that is on the same computer? The idea is that hopefully I could test and demonstrate with both the Java and Ruby on Rails running on my own computer then eventually use the same http request or a modification of it to connect to a server (when I eventually deploy the web-based application to the server).  If that could be done then how would it be done.  And, if it can't be done then what alternative exist.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HTTPPostRequestWithSocket {
public void sendRequest() {
    try {
        String params = URLEncoder.encode("param1", "UTF-8") + "="
                      + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
        params += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param2", "UTF-8") + "="
                      + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

        String hostname = "nameofthewebsite.com";
        int port = 80;

        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
        Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
        String path = "/nameofapp";

        // Send headers
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
        wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.0rn");
        wr.write("Content-Length: " + params.length() + "rn");
        wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
        wr.write("rn");

        // Send parameters
        wr.write(params);
        wr.flush();

        // Get response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        wr.close();
        rd.close();
        socket.close(); // Should this be closed at this point?
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re *" web application [...] run on a virtual machine is it possible to make an http request that, for demonstration/testing purposes, can connect from a Java to a Rails application that is on the same computer?"*

With the network properly configured in the VM configuration the guest system looks like an ordinary host (with its own unique MAC and IP address) to any other host on the network. So yes, it is possible.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  But what would need to be modified to make that work?  Since an HTML POST request uses a url to locate the second app then wouldn't that require the Rails application to be running from a server?

Comment: @Daron I'm sorry, I deleted my previous comment since after rethinking I thought it wasn't what you were asking for. If it was helpful I'll repeat it.
If I understood your original question correctly the Rails app is your server app, right? Run this app on the VM guest system and you have your server.

Comment: [digged up from the backyard of my brain] @Daron An UR[IL] doesn't necessarily need a registerd (e.g. DNS) host name. It can be an IP address as well, see [RFC 3986, 3.2.2. Host](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2). For instance [http://198.252.206.16/](http://198.252.206.16/).

Comment: If you are able to repeat it then that would be much appreciated.  I understand I'm somewhat confused.  But are you saying that in place of the URL I would

Comment: figure out the IP of the virtual machine?

Comment: The Java desktop app is sending information via HTTP POST request to the Rails app, which is located on the PCs virtual machine.

Comment: @Daron If it is your VM on your own computer it is up to you to define the IP in the guest system. There's no need of figuring it out. You simply know it by looking into the guest system's network config.

Comment: @Daron _"in place of the URL"_ is the wrong term. The URL is the entire string you normally see in your browser's address bar. It's "in place of the _host name_" you put the IP.

Comment: I see what you're saying.